# How to check IsHomePage in Magento 2? Are we on the homepage?

Tags: magento2

I want check current page is home page, category page, product page & cms page in magento 2

Comment: in what context do you want to check this? controller? block?

Comment: Magento 1 version we use function Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_header')->getIsHomePage(); i want to show data pagewise like homepage,category page,product page & cms page etc

Comment: I know that, but in order to answer this I want to know where do you want to use this in magento2. There is not global mage class in m2.

Comment: Because of the design pattern Dependency Injection. You create a module to request a resource on demand. Object manager is going against that paradigm. However, it works great but its like using Mage all over again--slow.

Answer (score 22):

You can try this:
Inject an instance of `\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http` in your class constructor. If you are in a controller you don't need to do it. You can already access it like this `$request = $this->getRequest()`

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
) {
    ...
    $this->_request = $request;
}
```

Then you can check if is homepage like this:

```
if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'cms_index_index') {
    //you are on the homepage
}
if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_product_view') {
    //you are on the product page
}
if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_category_view') {
    //you are on the category page
}
```

Comment: @marius - how do i check the same in a phtml file ?

Comment: write a method in the block that returns `$this->_request->getFullActionName()` ad use it in the phtml file.

Comment: Could you elaborate? How does one do that?

Comment: @Max what more elaboration do you need? I think the answer is clear? tell me what you want to know

Comment: Sorry, I re-read it and its clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

From inside phtml file this worked for me:

```
if ($this->getRequest()->getFullActionName() == 'cms_index_index') {
    //you are on the homepage
}
if ($this->getRequest()->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_product_view') {
    //you are on the product page
}
if ($this->getRequest()->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_category_view') {
    //you are on the category page
}
```

Comment: it works for me

Answer (score 5):

Try this one:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$request = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context')->getRequest();
if ($request->getFullActionName() == 'cms_index_index') {
    // is homepage
}
```

Comment: don't use object manager

Comment: This worked for me. Why not use Object Manager?

Comment: It's bad practice to use the Object Manager directly. [Magento Official dev doc](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/object-manager.html)  says "Magento prohibits the direct use of the ObjectManager in your code because it hides the real dependencies of a class."

Answer (score 1):

**Try below code:**

```
protected $_logo;   

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo $logo,
    array $data = []
)
{       
    $this->_logo = $logo;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function isHomePage()
{   
    return $this->_logo->isHomePage();
}
```

**Using Object Manager**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$logo = $objectManager->get('Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo');
var_dump($logo->isHomePage());
```

Answer (score 0):

In .phtml file you can do this

```
if ($this->getRequest()->getFullActionName() == 'cms_index_index') {
   // is homepage
}
```