# How to get RefererUrl in magento 2 observer?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, url, controllers, referral

How to get RefererUrl (source page url) in Observer file?

Actually by using this;

`$this->_redirect->getRefererUrl()`;

I am getting Referer Url in magento 2 controller file.But in Observer file I am not getting the source url (RefererUrl).

Can you help me on this ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make your observer class look like this:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

class ClassNameHere implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    protected $redirect;
    public function __construct(
        ....
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect,
        ...
    ) {
        ...
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
        ....
    }
}
```

then you can get the referer url in your `execute` method like this

```
$redirectUrl = $this->redirect->getRedirectUrl();
```

Comment: hi @Marius, can we get controller ad action name from getRefererUrl?

Answer (score 6):

yourObserverFile.php

```
class ClassNameHere implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    protected $redirect;
    public function __construct(
        ....
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect,
        ...
    ) {
        ...
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
        ....
    }
   public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
     return $redirectUrl = $this->redirect->getRefererUrl();
    }
}
```

Following line will help you to get refferer Url.

**$this->redirect->getRefererUrl();**

Comment: fyi i'd avoid the `die` here, also no need to assign to var. execute can just `return $this->redirect->getRefererUrl();`

Comment: i know, this is the solution code, anyone can test,  i have added and printed refferer url  for others who dont understand easily, you dont want to use die or echo...just do return..

Comment: @ManiMaranA, how to check if the referral url us forgot password page?

Comment: can we get controller and action name from getRefererUrl?

Comment: try this...
$url = 'https://www.test.com/customer/account/forgotpassword/';

if (strpos($url,'forgotpassword') !== false) {
    echo 'Forget Password page';
} else {
    echo 'other page.';
}

Comment: otherwise follow this  =>
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
) {
    ...
    $this->_request = $request;
}
then follows,

if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'customer_account_forgotpassword') {
    //you are on the forgotpassword page
}
=> Reference link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93148/how-to-check-ishomepage-in-magento-2-are-we-on-the-homepage