# Redirect to Referrer URL after Login with Facebook/Google not working

Tags: magento2, login, redirect, referral

Magento has a feature to redirect to the referrer page after a customer logs in.

I have done this using the following code:

```
$referer_url = $this->_redirect->getRefererUrl();

$CustomRedirectionUrl = $url->getUrl('customer/account/login',
    array('referer' => base64_encode($referer_url)));
```

But this referrer URL is not working with `Facebook/Google` signup; it is redirecting to the `My Account` page.

Comment: Can this help you? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/161634/how-to-get-refererurl-in-magento-2-observer

Comment: @IrfanMomin sir. You can approve this answer if it is useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$objecturl = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data');

echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/login', array('referer' => $objecturl->getEncodedUrl($this->getUrl('action where you want to redirect'))))
```

**Note : Do not use direct ObjectManager.**

Comment: Dont provide solutions and state afterwards that one shouldn't do it.